# Eclipse Luna on Retina MBP blurry text

Tags: eclipse, macos, retina-display

I recently upgraded to Eclipse Luna on my Retina Macbook Pro. It looks terrible. It must be running on a lower resolution and failing at scaling. I have searched and found to add:

```
<key>NSHighResolutionCapable</key>
    <true/>
```

to my info.Plist. That key is already there, and it still looks awful. How do I make it not kill my eyes?

Answer (score 0):

I had the same issue and I fixed it.

What I did was opening:
/Eclipse.app/Contents/Info.plist with en editor and add the following before :

```
<key>NSHighResolutionCapable</key>
```

`<true/>`

(You shoud probably already have it).

Right after, I tried to open Eclipse.app and it didn't work.

Then, I duplicated the Eclipse.app file (Named it Eclipse-retina.app in the same directory), just to make sure the OS refresh the config for the route, and it worked !

Let me know if it worked for you !